# How would one enable AHCI mode on a Dell Optiplex 320?

Tags: ahci, dell-optiplex

How would one go about enabling AHCI mode on a Dell Optiplex 320?
I have installed a SanDisk Ultra+ 256Gb SSD and cloned my Windows 8.1.1 install over, then re-aligned the partitions, but I'm still getting "pciide - BAD" in AS SSD benchmark, so I wish to use AHCI.
I have looked in the BIOS but cannot find an option for changing the
setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like it supports it.  The ATI chipset in it ([Radeon Xpress 200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpress_200#Radeon_Xpress_200_for_Intel)) was used by Intel for a very short period (just before AMD bought ATI) on some low-end boards, and it sucked/had limited features (based on personal experience with a few of them back in the day).

It CAN support AHCI and RAID, but probably wasn't implemented by Intel/Dell in your system.  The lack of the options in the BIOS (and no mention of either [in the manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-320_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf), beyond the Glossary) supports this.

If not already, you may want to try latest BIOS for that motherboard -- but I'd say you're unfortunately out of luck -- the board most likely just doesn't support it.

Comment: Would it be possible to overrride dell/intel and enable anyway?

Comment: No, because it's not actually implemented in the hardware.  You'll need a newer/better motherboard.

Comment: @Ƭ Oh, darnit! Meh, getting a new machine soon...